# SMD diode value

Tags: diodes, surface-mount

I need to change surface-mount diode but i need to know its value.
possible your assistance to know the value of the diode in the picture.
what is the value of diode in picture? 
or how to get the value?

[image: diode photo]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "value"? Reverse voltage? Forward current? Power rating? Model number?

Comment: Diodes have many values. You may want to edit you question so that it is more clear. 
Generally, if the diode is just there for reverse voltage protection, you could use any other of-the-shelve SMD diode. The round ones usually dont have any manufacturer markings on them

Answer (score 7):

There is no way you can reliably get the type or parameters of such a diode from a picture or even from the physical diode itself.

Your best bet is to get the circuit diagram or the components list (assuming the PCB has component identifications).

Lacking that, you (or we) could make an educated guess based on the type of circuit in which it is used.

If all else fails, you could try the universal jellybean: 1N4148. (Which, as Spehro says, is called LL4148 in its SMD version.)

Comment: +1 specifically LL4148 for something that 'looks' like this one (MELF)